# Expiration Date using blpapi

Tags: python, api

How can I use the bloomberg api to get the expiration date of a contract (I have the ticker)?

I have tried multiple terms but nothing seems to work. For example,

```
blp.bdh(tickers=['KC1 Comdty'],flds=['LAST_TRADE_DATE'])
```

Answer (score 1):

bdh is for historical requests. You probably want bdp.

Also, check that the field exists in the terminal by typing FLDS

Answer (score 0):

```
blp.bdp(tickers=[tickers],flds=['FUT_LAST_TRADE_DT']
```